# I am unable to build A program in codeblocks

Tags: codeblocks

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PN2HT.png)

I am continuously facing the error in building my code and saving it and running it in codeblocks. For this, I reinstalled codeblocks many a times. I have already gone through stackoverflow for answers on such questions and tried them but nothing is helping me. The bottom lines in the picture can help you guys get an idea of what is happening. Thank you for your cooperation.

Comment: What happens when you build and run it ?
Does it show an error at the time of build or run? What is the error?

Comment: I saw youtube video and it got fixed . thank you .